# Update GridView via Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have my GridView working. I enabled Edit, Delete, and Update columns. My StoredProcedure only selects the data that fills the GridView.

Am I supposed to make one StoredProcedure that can Select, Update, and Delete or use 3 separate StoredProcedures?

How do I reference and code the Update and Delete in the GridView side?

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrants" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Events2 %>" 
SelectCommand="spGetRegistrantsGridView"
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

StoredProcedure (Only Select Statement)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetRegistrantsGridView]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT FirstName,
        LastName,
        AddressLine1,
        AddressLine2,
        City,
        State,
        Zip,
        Country,
        Phone,
        PhoneExt,
        Email,
        Comments
    FROM Registrant
END
```

Comment: Have look at [GridView CRUD: Select Insert Edit Update Delete using Single Stored Procedure in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-Delete-using-Single-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet.aspx) it'll give you a really good idea

Comment: Thank you! This looks perfect.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. Good luck with your project

Comment: @Izzy I followed this and I get this error: `Procedure or function 'spRegistrantsGridView' expects parameter '@RegistrantId', which was not supplied.` in the very beginning at `sda.Fill(dt);`

Comment: You need to provide the `@RegistrantId` parameter to your `SP` then it should work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at this. should include what you need:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/insert-update-delete-in-gridview-using-single-stored-proce/